# How to call a nested class in my activity to be able to use its methods

Tags: java, android

how are you?,I hope it's ok, I am trying to call these nested classes in my activity but it is not throwing an error

```
  public class StateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
 {
            public void method1(Context context, Intent intent){
                                  
               
                 }

public class PhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
       public void method2 (int var, String var2)
    {
         }

  }
}}
```

I am calling it in the following way

```
PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver myClass = new PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver();
```

This is an example of the code that I want to implement:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/ebweb-lab/CodeExampleTele/blob/main/Codeexample.java)

I would like to know how to call a class since I would like to implement it in a button,Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your `PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver ` class and where do you declare it

Comment: I have the class independently, and I would like to declare it in an activity, but I would not know how to do it, I have seen many examples in google but I have not achieved it yet, sorry for the ignorance but I am new to android development,

Comment: Can you please provide a complete code snippet

Comment: @tendai That is the base code, in my app there more code inside the methods but simply
I just want to know how I can access the methods of those nested classes from my mainactivity,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, we cannot call a class in java.We call the members(instance variables and methods).
2. PhoneStateListener is extending the PhoneStateListener itself.This creates a cycle and will throw an error at the compile time.
3. PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver myClass = new PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver(); //  I couldn't find any class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver in the given code.So I dont know how this works.
4. Finally, You have stated that you didn't get any error from the given code snippet.I'm not sure whether you are using any IDE for coding but if you are using any , the IDE itself will show you the errors.

Comment: Well, how could I access the methods of those classes from an activity?

Comment: If the Nested class is a static class and if the methods in it are also static you can call those methods in the following manner.Lets Assume class "TestA" has a nested static class "TestB" and TestB has a static method run(). we can call run() by TestA.TestB.run();
if the clas and the methods in class "TestB" is non static then we  can call by: TestB obj = new TestA.TestB();obj.run();
If nested clas is static and if its members are also static you can cal them without using the new keyword(As done in ex:1).if the class and members are non static,you shd use new keyword to call methods(Ex:2)

Comment: I have added a content so that you have an idea of ​​the code that I want to implement in my activity